# How to shift SVN revisions, merging two revisions together?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I have a situation when SVN revisions need to be decreased by 1. 
This means that if there are only 3 revisions, I need the first one and the second one to be merged together with their comments, so there remain only two revisions:

- 1st and 2nd merged -> became 1st
- 3rd -> became 2nd

Is there a way to do this?

I hope, the question is clear. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is unclear just because you never need this in practice.

Comment: If there're really only three revisions you'll have to create a new repository, commit there as desired and then discard the old repo. However, if this is something that really matters and it's likely to happen in the future you might have chosen the wrong version control tool.

Answer (score 1):

Revisions in Subversion are immutable:

> Revisions are immutable trees that build upon one another. Removing a
>   revision from history would cause a domino effect, creating chaos in
>   all subsequent revisions and possibly invalidating all working copies.

Therefore, there is no easy way to do this without major repository surgery that will affect all its users. And you don't need to do this. You should describe the actual problem you are trying to solve; there have to be better solutions than the one you currently think of.